# I need to create a pop up window when i click the data from my loop

Tags: javascript, php, html

When i click any of the result data of my table it will open a pop up window.

```
<?php
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $date = $row['Date'];
    echo '<tr> <td><a href="googlemap.php?googlemap.php?Date='.$row['Date'].'"'.$date.'</a></td></tr>;
 }
?>
```

Comment: A Pop-Up Window that does what? Opens the `googlemap.php?googlemap.php?Date=-----` Link?

Comment: First; your `<a>` Tag is not properly formatted. Secondly: you can do that directly with raw Javascript or JS Library like JQuery... by binding the `click` event to a function either within the Tag or  within a script block......

Answer (score 0):

You can use [window.open](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml) for this.

```
 <?php
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $date = $row['Date'];
    echo '<tr> <td><a href="googlemap.php?googlemap.php?Date='.$row['Date'].'" onclick="window.open(this.href, \'googlemap\',\'height=500,width=500\');return false;">'.$date.'</a></td></tr>;}
 ?>
```

Comment: tried but not working its just opening a new tab and not a pop up window

Comment: Updated my answer, it will show the window now in popup

Answer (score 0):

Since the solution with inline javascript offered by @vher2 seems not to do the trick for you; perhaps you could try another option that uses a script-block. The code below shows how.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showPopUp(elem){
        var popupURL   = elem.getAttribute('href');
        window.open(popupURL, "Google Map", "width=800, height=500");
        return false;
    }
</script>

<?php

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $date = $row['Date'];
        echo '<tr>
                <td>
                    <a  onclick="showPopUp(this);return false;"
                        class="map-link"
                        href="googlemap.php?googlemap.php?Date=' . $date . '">' . $date . '</a>
                </td>
              </tr>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: is there a way that i can remove the border of my popup window??